# add remove dynamic select box not add data to dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for add dynamic select box and load select2 search for each like this:

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attribute_row = <?= $attribute_row; ?>;

    function addAttribute() {
        html = '<tr id="attribute-row' + attribute_row + '">';
        html += '  <td class="text-left"><input type="text" name="product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][name]" class="attribute-name' + attribute_row + '" value=""><select id="' + attribute_row + '" name="product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][attribute_id]" class="form-control attributeSelect">';
        html += '  </select></td>';
        html += '  <td><div class="icheck-primary"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAttribute' + attribute_row + '" name="product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][visible_on_product]" value="1"><label for="checkboxAttribute' + attribute_row + '"></label></div></td>';
        html += '  <td><input type="text" name="product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][text]" value="" placeholder="<?= lang('Product.price'); ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '  ';
        html += '  <td><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#attribute-row' + attribute_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= lang('Product.removeAttribute'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#attribute tbody').append(html);
        $(".attributeSelect").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            theme: 'bootstrap4',
            width: 'auto',
            ajax: {
                url: "url",
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: params.term,
                        csrf_token: csfr_token // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                    return {
                        results: response
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        }).on("select2:select", function () {
            data = $(".attributeSelect").select2('data')[0];
            id = $('.attributeSelect').attr('id');
            $(".attribute-name" + id).val(data.text);
        });
        attribute_row++;
    }
</script>
```

in Action after search and select(`on select`) result i need to add select2 `data.text` into this input box:

```php
<input type="text" name="product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][name]" class="attribute-name' + attribute_row + '" value="">
```

my code work for first select box and add value to first input box But for second and more also add data to first input.

[image]

how do can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always getting the first id when doing this for all the items with that class:

`id = $('.attributeSelect').attr('id');`

That's why it's setting always the result the first element. You should get the current id of the element receiving the event. You can probably receive that from the event object:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```